# Connecting a VM to a VNet on different subscription in Azure

Tags: virtual-machines, azure, azure-networking

I recently migrated a VM from classic to resource manager and changed the subscription to be able to attach it to a certain virtual network.

I need to switch the VM back to the other subscription while keeping it attached to the v-net.  In the portal it returns errors when trying to move the VM or the resource group it's in.  The errors are from the virtual network,etc being in a different subscription.

I was wondering if anyone knew any workarounds using powershell, etc.

Comment: Azure support responded to my ticket and clarified that you cannot have a VM attached to a V-Net on different subscriptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand what you exactly mean, the solution to your problem is, first to delete VM (NOT THE STORAGE) and then to deploy VM on your VNET.
If you mean something else please send more details about the error.

Answer (score 0):

*Regrettably, a virtual machine alone cannot be moved to a different subscription as the machine needs a network available in the subscription where it is.
However, you can copy underlying the disks of the virtual machine to the destination subscription and create the same VM with the copied disks in a new network available in the destination subscription.*
-Azure Support

Comment: You COULD peer vnets between different subscriptions, if all you are trying to do is keep network connectivity between those machines.  Setup the VM on a vnet in subscription a and peer the vnet with vnet in sub b.

Answer (score 0):

It is obvious that a virtual machine cannot exists without a network. My answer was based on a previous ticket, on Ms Support.
Did you solve your problem or not ?
If you don't then give more details, to help you..